# Order product without gateway

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I would like "buy" product without the use of a gateway. The reason for this is that the customer will have the option to apply for a loan at the bank and when the loan it approved we'll get a callback and then the order will be executed.

Does anyone have a good idea for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you're looking for is under Commerce Settings->Payment Methods, set the "Credit Card Payement Type" to "Authorize Only (Manual Capture)", then set the "Payment Gateway" to "Dummy".

Comment: Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Nice... feel free to mark as the answer if you'd like.

Comment: I *think* the intention is actually to use the 'Manual' gateway for payment types like this (where there is no actual payment via Commerce) and the Dummy one for setup/testing credit card type payments.  That's what Luke told me awhile ago anyway I'm pretty sure :) Not sure if it's a big deal but might have some implications for order histories etc.